# What is the correct syntax to create a procedure in MySQL to insert data?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to insert data into a table.

The procedure which I wrote is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insrtem (IN x int(3),IN y varchar(3))

BEGIN

    insert into emp (empid,empname) values (x,y);
END;
```

but it doesn't work.

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: You should specify what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you often need a `delimiter` statement, so that is my first guess:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE insrtem (IN in_x signed, IN in_y varchar(3))
BEGIN
    insert into emp (empid, empname)
        values (in_x, in_y);
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Notice I changed the names of the parameters to have an `in` prefix.  This helps distinguish the parameters from columns in the table.